# File splitting loss of data

Tags: java, file-io

I wrote a program for file splitting and joining. When I break the file into small pieces I found that the size of smaller file is not equal to the original one, there is loss of approximately 30-50 bytes of data. and the combined file doesn't run correctly

e.g. a file **ABC** has been broken into 2 parts, **ABC1** and **ABC2** but the problem is
`sizeof(ABC)` is **not equal to** `sizeof(ABC1)` + `sizeof(ABC2)`. By `sizeof(ABC)` I mean from Windows's perspective, i.e. from the Windows property dialog box.

My code is:

```
for(int i =0;i<no_of_parts;i++)
{
       copied_data = 0;// a variable that count the no of byte transferred in the part of file
       fos = new FileOutputStream(jTextField2.getText()+"\\".part"+i);
       bouts = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
       while((b = bins.read())!= -1)
       {
             bouts.write(b);
             copied_data++;
             if(copied_data==each_part_size_in_byte)
                break;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about closing your output stream? It will flush the buffer and free the file descriptor you use. Call `bouts.close()`.

Comment: i add this bouts.close() in my code but still the same problem is coming, when i join my file it doesn run and data is still lost.

Comment: can I see where you add it? also add the code of the file joining.

Comment: with close() i needs to add flush(), after that it works. thanks

Comment: `close()` always calls `flush()` for you. You must always close the outer most/last stream you create in a chain.  If you close the file instead of the buffer, any buffered data will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a file, it is created in blocks of memories instead of individual bytes. So when you divide the file into two, both of them have sizes in fixed blocks which may be more than your actual size of the written data.

Comment: but my actual size is grater than fragmented file size. i.e data is losing.